# How do I check if there is a role that contains certain text in it?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Let me explain:
I want to search through all the roles in the guild to find a role that contains the text "Mod", i.e. "MODerator".

This is the code I have right now:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
      if (msg.author == client.user){return}
      let message = msg.content.toLowerCase()
      let allowedRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Mod");
      if (message.includes("e!"))
      {

        if (message.includes('automod') && allowedRole)
        {
          if (automodOn)
          {
            automodOn = false;
            msg.channel.send("Automod has been `deactivated`.")
          }
          else
          {
            automodOn = true;
            msg.channel.send("Automod has been `activated`.")
          }
        }
```

What this code does is searching for a role that it's name is specifically "Mod". What I need it to do, as I already said, is for it to search for a role **containing** the text "Mod".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've already used `.includes()` is there a reason you chose not to do that in your `find()` call?

Comment: It says that .includes() is not a function

Comment: But you accepted an answer that does exactly what I said? Interesting.

Comment: Oh wait I didn't understand your answer. I thought you were talking about msg.guild.roles.cache.find, not the r.name.find. I tried that and it worked. Sorry :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const allowedRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name.includes("Mod"));
```